# Dagger 2 not injecting, lateinit property not initialized

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I am trying to inject Context using Dagger 2. I have seen many other questions on this website related to this but still problem is not solved.

AppComponent.kt:

```
@Singleton
@Component(
    modules = [
        AppModule::class
    ]
)
interface AppComponent {
    fun context(): Context
    fun inject(context: Context)
}
```

AppModule.kt:

```
@Module
class AppModule(private val context: Context) {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun providesApplicationContext(): Context = context
}
```

MainApp.kt:

```
class MainApp : Application() {
    lateinit var appComponent: AppComponent

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        appComponent = initDagger()
        appComponent.inject(this)
    }

    private fun initDagger() = DaggerAppComponent.builder()
        .appModule(AppModule(this))
        .build()
}
```

Manager.kt: (Class where I want to inject Context)

```
class Manager {

    @Inject
    lateinit var context: Context

    fun foo() {
       context.resources
    }
}
```

However, I am getting following error at `context.resources` when `Manager().foo()` is called from anywhere, say in `onCreate()` function of `MainActivity`:

```
kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property context has not been initialized
```

How to fix this? Why is Dagger not injecting `Context`?

Comment: The question does not contain where `Manager` is created or used?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce question updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `constructor` injection

```
class Manager @Inject constructor(val context: Context) {

    fun foo() {
       context.resources
    }
}
```

And then in your `Activity/Fragment` use `manager` like below:

```
@Inject lateinit var manager: Manager
```

Comment: To work `lateinit var` you have to inject the `Manager` to dagger

Comment: Can you please explain how can I do that?

Comment: I am getting error `No value passed for parameter 'context'` in `Manager()` after I did above change.

Comment: No need to pass `context` to create `Manager`. Just use `@Inject lateinit var manager: Manager` in your `Activity/Fragment`